# After I export a GIMP image from XCF to JPG, will my comments from the GIMP image still show up?

Tags: gimp

The version of GIMP I am using is **2.10.22**.
I used "image properties" to add a comment (caption) to my photos. I closed and saved the image. Next, I edited the metadata, then exported the XCF image to JPG. After exporting the photo, I get a pop-up showing a preview of the metadata and comments, so I clicked "export" again.

On my desktop, I go into my folders and open the exported JPG image. All I see is the image itself with no comments or metadata. Is that supposed to happen?

My professor has a program where she can see any photo added in with a caption. I've submitted all 3 of my JPG photos (exported from GIMP).
So.. my question is: Will she be able to see all 3 captions and metadata from those photos? Or will she see JUST the photos?

It's my first time using this program..so I hope I did everything correctly.

My goal is to have her see everything.
I'm on thin ice as of now..

Comment: https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-images-out.html#save-export-image

Answer (score 1):

You have not said which version of Gimp you are using but in my version (2.10.18) I can open an image and view the metadata by choosing menu option `Image -> Metadata -> View Metadata` so use that function to see what metadata your exported image has.

And when you export to JPG there are options on the export window `Save Exif data / Save XMP data / Save IPTC data` if you don't want any metadata in the exported image then un-check those boxes.

Comment: I am using 2.10.22

Answer (score 0):

The default image viewer of Ubuntu 20.04 lets you see the meta data of images by clicing the three-lined button (top right corner), choosing Image Properties, and choosing the Metadata tab. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things:

1. the JPEG comment. This is part of the JPEG standard itself, independently of the EXIF metadata. On Linux, the `file` command displays it. In Gimp , this is the "Comment" in `Image>Properties`, and also the comment that you can enter in the JPEG export dialog.
2. The EXIF/IPTC metadata: the EXIF-standard medata, which is Gimp is in the `Image>Metadata` dialog.

So after filling these two dialogs with this:

[image]

You can check the result

*with the `file` command (see "description"):

```
file /tmp/empty.jpg 
/tmp/empty.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 300x300, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=8, description=From the comments tab, xresolution=132, yresolution=140, resolutionunit=2, software=GIMP 2.10.14, datetime=2020:11:19 12:04:25, GPS-Data], comment: "From the comments tab", progressive, precision 8, 400x400, components 3
```

or with the `exiftool` command (in the repos) (see "Comment", "Description", "Title", "Creator", "Image description":

```
exiftool /tmp/empty.jpg 
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.65
File Name                       : empty.jpg
Directory                       : /tmp
File Size                       : 6.7 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:11:19 12:04:31+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:11:19 12:04:31+01:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:11:19 12:04:31+01:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Description               : From the comments tab
X Resolution                    : 300
Y Resolution                    : 300
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : GIMP 2.10.14
Modify Date                     : 2020:11:19 12:04:25
User Comment                    : From the comments tab
Color Space                     : sRGB
GPS Latitude                    : 0 deg 0' 0.00"
GPS Longitude                   : 0 deg 0' 0.00"
GPS Altitude                    : 0 m
XMP Toolkit                     : XMP Core 4.4.0-Exiv2
Digital Source Type             : http://cv.iptc.org/newscodes/digitalsourcetype/digitalCapture
Document ID                     : gimp:docid:gimp:243d0396-1a39-452e-9928-9e8ead6b184f
Instance ID                     : xmp.iid:ab683835-93fb-4b83-b27b-7377bc343fa8
Original Document ID            : xmp.did:8a5b06ea-f663-4db9-a56f-5c8ab1bbe735
Model Release Status            : None
Api                             : 2.0
Platform                        : Linux
Time Stamp                      : 1605783871557164
Version                         : 2.10.14
Format                          : image/jpeg
Creator Tool                    : GIMP 2.10
Location Created                : 
Location Shown                  : 
Artwork Or Object               : 
Registry ID                     : 
History Action                  : saved, saved
History Changed                 : /metadata, /
History Instance ID             : xmp.iid:4f8c50bb-8928-455c-add3-f987de0a63fe, xmp.iid:89777edf-dae6-412f-883a-9fa73b3728e7
History Software Agent          : Gimp 2.10 (Linux), Gimp 2.10 (Linux)
History When                    : +01:00, +01:00
Image Supplier                  : 
Image Creator                   : 
Copyright Owner                 : 
Licensor                        : 
Creator                         : type="Seq" Metadata author
Description                     : Metadata description
Title                           : Metadata title
Profile CMM Type                : Little CMS
Profile Version                 : 4.3.0
Profile Class                   : Display Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 2020:11:19 11:02:10
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Apple Computer Inc.
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             : 
Device Model                    : 
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : Little CMS
Profile ID                      : 0
Profile Description             : GIMP built-in sRGB
Profile Copyright               : Public Domain
Media White Point               : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Chromatic Adaptation            : 1.04788 0.02292 -0.05022 0.02959 0.99048 -0.01707 -0.00925 0.01508 0.75168
Red Matrix Column               : 0.43604 0.22249 0.01392
Blue Matrix Column              : 0.14305 0.06061 0.71393
Green Matrix Column             : 0.38512 0.7169 0.09706
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 32 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 32 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 32 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Chromaticity Channels           : 3
Chromaticity Colorant           : Unknown (0)
Chromaticity Channel 1          : 0.64 0.33002
Chromaticity Channel 2          : 0.3 0.60001
Chromaticity Channel 3          : 0.15001 0.06
Device Mfg Desc                 : GIMP
Device Model Desc               : sRGB
Comment                         : From the comments tab
Image Width                     : 400
Image Height                    : 400
Encoding Process                : Progressive DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 400x400
Megapixels                      : 0.160
GPS Position                    : 0 deg 0' 0.00", 0 deg 0' 0.00"
```

Comment: But will she be able to see all 3 comments? That's my question..

Comment: Gimps put them where they should be